# Chunked undo in TextMate

Tags: macos, textmate

TextMate undoes typed text one character at a time. I'm using chunked undo to mean the OS X standard behavior where undo applies for everything typed after a retype delay. Can TextMate do this?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is and what you want.

Comment: Come on, TextMate's undo is like Finder's cut — it's been one of the top feature requests for ages. But to be more specific, TM undoes typed text one character at a time. I'm using chunked undo to mean the OS X standard behavior where undo applies for everything typed after a retype delay.

Comment: Details belongs in questions, not comments.

Comment: Btw, to fill my off topic comment quota for the day, congrats on the 1k rep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a cross-site dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247568/how-can-i-undo-more-than-a-single-character-in-textmate).

Judging from the release notes (*Help » Release Notes*) nothing has been changed about Undo since its developer Allan Odgaard commented [here](http://nslog.com/2006/11/08/textmates_undo) in Nov 2006:

> [...] many users do indeed share your hate of the non-chunked undo, and it will change sometime in the future.

Since then, only rather minor changes in TextMate have occurred, none of them related to undo/redo. A user on the TextMate blog [commented](http://blog.macromates.com/2010/why-2-0-is-not-developed-in-the-open/) about a year ago:

> TM1 is great, which a buch of features, but what i really miss in the correct undo behaviour.
>
> Undo one char by time is a disaster for a lot of chars. (of course it makes you a better programmer, because you make less mistakes to avoid this TM1 "bug", hehe).
>
> If that can be fixed, as a release to TM1 i would gladly wait for TM2 (or whatever) the time it takes to be ready.

Since then, only three *very* minor revisions to TextMate have been released.

---

[Recently](http://chipotle.tumblr.com/post/5207966724/text-editor-intervention), via [Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2011/05/05/text-editor-intervention):

> TM has always been a mix of sheer brilliance and stone cold stupid, and while the former outweighs the latter, when the latter pops up it really gets in your face. (Undo character by character, anyone?)

Appears to be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

TextMate 2 has chunked undo. Any remaining TextMate 1 users should upgrade.